# React Redux Store variable not found, even though it is in store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am working on a react-native project with redux.
So far I succesfully connected redux to one screen and I am trying to connect the next one, the first one is running just fine.
Problem is I get :

TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentView' of undefined

while trying to retrieve a value from the store.

My store is succesfully set up and intialized:
https://ibb.co/WxrKMgh
(Everything also works on the first screen)

My implementation (abreviated for better readability):

```js
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component {
    public state: any;
    public props: any;
    public setState: any;
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.props.authentication.currentView === 'initializing' && (
                    <InitializationScreen />
                )}
                {'hallo' == 'mainNav' && <AppContainer />}
            </>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
    const { currentView } = state;
    return {
        currentView,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Problematic code:

```
{this.props.authentication.currentView === 'initializing' && (
                <InitializationScreen />
            )}
```

Can you see what is causing the error?

Thanks a lot!

---

For future reference I found a solution:

i changed mapstatetoprops to :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
const { currentView } = state.authentication;
return {
    currentView,
};
};
```

It is basically the same, but for whatever reason, this way it works (although it should be exactly the same)

State in mapStateToProps:

```
{
"search": {
"searchType": "Quick Search",
},
"authentication": {
"currentView": "mainNav"
}
}
```

Comment: What is `state` in mapStateToProps and can you add it to your question? You can console.log it with `console.log(JSON.stringify(state,undefined,2))` in mapStateToProps

Comment: Hey thanks for your support, I posted it aswell. I found a solution changing my mapstatetoprops, although I don't really understand how this change "fixed" it, since I am bascially doing the same

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `currentView` as toplevel prop to the component, so it should be available in in `this.props`

```
this.props.currentView === 'initializing' && (
                <InitializationScreen />
            )}
```

Comment: Hey ssk! Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it is still not working. I created a log function : log(currentView: any) {
        console.log(currentView);
    } and ran it with {this.log(this.props.currentView)} . Console log says undefined

Comment: Try a `console.log(this.props);` just after `render() {` as the first line of render function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found a solution that seems to be working! (Although it is weird to me as it should have before)

Answer (score 2):

I think that It should be `this.props.currentView`

Answer (score 0):

Please use this.props.currentview 
**because its calling from somewhere else**